# using blender, how to add armature to svg image

Tags: image, svg, blender-2.76

I have 2d image of a person and converted the same into svg file, uploaded the file into blender and tried to add armature to it but somehow i could not find any relavant controls to bind armature to human shape(svg). Could anybody share the supporting docs..

Thanks
ASH

Comment: Try here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

by adding armature plugin to blender tool complete human shaped armature option will be available under ADD-->Armature-->Human(Meta-Rig)

However complete 3d model cannot be generated from the svg object. At max all parts of the image object can be extruded.

Thanks
ASH